# Switching to cached resolution causing project to throw errors in runtime

Tags: scala, jackson, sbt, jackson-databind

When using [updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cached-Resolution.html), our project is no longer working. First, SLF4J started throwing errors saying no logger found in classpath. It was easy to fix by explicitly adding a logger such as `logback-common`. But we are also having issues with jackson. When I looked up the dependency graph, it seems like some libraries are using jackson 2.6, some are using 2.11 but we are explicitly adding 2.13 and using `dependencyOverrides` to make sure >2.12 is being used.

Even though I don't see any jar files of jackson-databind or anything related to jackson prior to 2.12 in my classpath when debugging, a method that exists in >2.12 is supposedly not found. It seems like a version of jackson <2.12 is trying to be called.

Note: I am using `sbt test` to test my changes.

So my questions are,

1. Why using cached resolution changed runtime behavior?
2. Why and how a version of jackson that is not shown in my classpath is being used?

Unfortunately I can't share code because this is a private project in company.

Error:

```
[error] Uncaught exception when running ...: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.JacksonFeatureSet com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.getReadCapabilities()'
[error] sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.JacksonFeatureSet com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.getReadCapabilities()'
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.<init>(DeserializationContext.java:212)
```

Comment: You sure can at least share your build.sbt and a minimal reproduction case. Can't you?

Comment: I can't share my build.sbt. It contains over 50+ subprojects and 100+ dependencies.

I am also not able to reproduce. If I can reproduce I will share.